# BDS with VBA - Input the expiration date in a cell to let VBA to read into the code

Tags: excel, vba

I have, in the Excel sheet, the following equation:

```
=BDS("SPX Index","CHAIN_TICKERS","CHAIN_POINTS_OVRD=ALL","CHAIN_STRIKE_PX_OVRD=ALL","CHAIN_EXP_DT_OVRD=201401","CHAIN_PUT_CALL_TYPE_OVRD=c","","cols=1;rows=201")
```

Then I have the following codes in VBA, so that I can push a batten and get the data I want:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim options As String

Cells(2, 1).Formula = StringConcat("", "=BDS(", _
Chr(34), "SPX Index", Chr(34), ",", _
Chr(34), "CHAIN_TICKERS", Chr(34), ",", _
Chr(34), "CHAIN_POINTS_OVRD=ALL", Chr(34), ",", _
Chr(34), "CHAIN_STRIKE_PX_OVRD=ALL", Chr(34), ",", _
Chr(34), "CHAIN_EXP_DT_OVRD=201401", Chr(34), ",", _
Chr(34), "CHAIN_PUT_CALL_TYPE_OVRD=c", Chr(34), ",", _
Chr(34), Chr(34), ")")
```

This is working well, except that I would like to figure out if there is anything I can do with this line: `Chr(34), "CHAIN_EXP_DT_OVRD=201401", Chr(34), ",", _`. Currently, I have to hard code and have to change every time If I want some different months data. I was wondering if someone can help me to code the part, so that I can bring the date from some cell on the spreadsheet instead of coming into VBA and change it.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=BDS(""SPX Index"",""CHAIN_TICKERS"",""CHAIN_POINTS_OVRD=ALL"",""CHAIN_STRIKE_PX_OVRD=ALL"",""CHAIN_EXP_DT_OVRD="" & $D$2 & """",""CHAIN_PUT_CALL_TYPE_OVRD=c"","""",""cols=1;rows=201"")"
```

with this, Range("$D$2"), ie, the Cells(2, 4), permits you to input year and month value dynamically.